How to work with a function that blocks a thread in python\aiogram3?
So, for a more detailed description of the problem, I will give an example of a small code:
import asyncio
from time import sleep
import logging

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, Router
from aiogram.filters import Command
from aiogram.types import Message


token = "<token>"

bot = Bot(token=token)
dispatcher = Dispatcher()

router = Router()
dispatcher.include_router(router)


def block_function() -> str:
    sleep(2)
    return "Complete!"


@router.message(Command("start"))
async def start(message: Message) -> None:
    username = message.from_user.username
    await message.answer(f"Hello, {username}!")
    await message.answer("Start...")
    await message.answer(block_function())


@router.message(Command("escape"))
async def stop_polling(message: Message) -> None:
    await message.answer("Bye!")
    await dispatcher.stop_polling()


async def main() -> None:
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    await dispatcher.start_polling(bot)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

I intentionally used a synchronous function in block_function(). In this case, it is obvious that for 2 seconds the bot will not be able to accept and process requests from users.
Question: what needs to be done in order to put the blocking function in a separate thread?
Known solutions: to make a synchronous function asynchronous, but, unfortunately, in a real project, this function is mathematical and cannot be asynchronous

asyncio.to_thread will help. dig on that

Thanks to Zwick Vitaly, the answer was found. Below I offer the corrected code, with the function asyncio.to_thread and a few additional examples:
import asyncio
from io import BytesIO
import logging
from time import sleep, time

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, Router
from aiogram.filters import Command
from aiogram.types import Message, BufferedInputFile

import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

mpl.use("agg")
plt.style.use("ggplot")


token = "<YOUR TOKEN HERE>"

bot = Bot(token=token)
dispatcher = Dispatcher()

router = Router()
dispatcher.include_router(router)


def block_plot_function(username: str) -> bytes:
    x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
    y = np.sin(x**2 - 1)

    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.title(f"example for {username}")
    plt.xlabel("x")
    plt.ylabel("y")

    image_bytes = BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(image_bytes, format="png")
    plt.close("all")

    image_bytes.seek(0)
    values = image_bytes.getvalue()
    image_bytes.close()

    return values


def block_math_function() -> str:
    M = np.random.randn(50) * 1e9

    start = time()
    for i in range(10000000):
        M = np.sqrt(M)

    return f"Complete in {time() - start} sec"


def block_sleep_function() -> str:
    sleep(2)
    return "Complete!"


@router.message(Command("check_sleep"))
async def check_sleep(message: Message) -> None:
    await message.answer("Start sleep check...")
    await message.answer(await asyncio.to_thread(block_sleep_function))


@router.message(Command("check_math"))
async def check_math(message: Message) -> None:
    await message.answer("Start math check...")
    await message.answer(await asyncio.to_thread(block_math_function))


@router.message(Command("check_plot"))
async def check_plot(message: Message) -> None:
    uname = message.from_user.username
    await message.answer("Start plot check...")
    values = await asyncio.to_thread(block_plot_function, username=uname)
    await message.answer_photo(BufferedInputFile(values, "example"))


@router.message(Command("escape"))
async def stop_polling(message: Message) -> None:
    await message.answer("Bye!")
    await dispatcher.stop_polling()


async def main() -> None:
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    await dispatcher.start_polling(bot)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())


please consider that heavy computation tasks should be delegated to multiprocessing or celery or other process-related solutions. learn about i\o-bound tasks and cpu-bound tasks. this is a key knowledge for python web-development
